# Parse file headers as date objects in Python/pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How can you to parse the headers in a csv file as dates? I'm trying to use some parameters in the `pandas.read_csv` function:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(path, header=1, infer_datetime_format=1, parse_dates=True)
```

But nothing in data is formatted as dates but the headers of columns 2 to 6.

I tried to use indexing to `parse_dates` like `parse_dates=columns[2,3,4,5,6]`, but it throws an error, because `columns` is not recognize at this stage.

raw csv:

```
Name,Adm.,1980-12-31,1992-12-31,2002-05-20,2011-03-31,2015-12-31,Area
Aleksandrów Łódzki,LOD,"17.000","20.251","20.220","21.085","21.354",1382
Andrychów,MAL,"19.400","23.144","22.187","21.530","20.940",1033
```

Reads in a follows:

```
print(data[0:2])

Aleksandrów Łódzki  LOD     17.000  20.251  20.220  21.085  21.354  1382
Andrychów   MAL     19.400  23.144  22.187  21.530  20.940  1033 1
Augustów    POD     24.300  29.089  29.705  30.802  30.400  8090 2
```

**EDIT**

I'm sorry. I'd like to delete this post. There was an error in my csv file. Headers should look like:

`Miasto,Adm,"1980-12-31","1992-12-31","2002-05-20","2011-03-31","2015-12-31",Area`

Namely, with quotes in dates. And then everything is automaticly all right. My mistake. Maybe it'd be challenging for those who hasn't got an access to csv files. Ha ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are after is to rename the columns after you read in the `csv` file as:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, infer_datetime_format=1, parse_dates=True)
columns = {}
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        columns[col] = pd.to_datetime(col, infer_datetime_format=True)
    except ValueError:
        pass
df.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)
```

Comment: To be consistent: Your solution works fine. The dates are with time but this is not important. `1980-12-31 00:00:00`. I wondered, if the conversion after the read of data is would be possible, because the fields was formated just like float numbers.